# Trying to form an array that takes it's size from tuple unpacking by only taking the integers in a tuple

Tags: python

```
if (type(n) == int):
    y = np.zeros(n)
    y[0] = seed
elif (type(n) == tuple):
    for a,b in n:
        if (type(a) == int):
            y = np.zeros(a)
            y[0] = seed
        elif (type(b) == int):
            y = np.zeros(b)
            y[0] = seed
```

I have been trying to get this code to via tuple unpacking to only take integers that are input into the tuple and use that integer to form an array full of zeroes with the integer being used to form its size and discard the rest, however I can't seem to avoid getting the error message that is a 
**TypeError:  'int' object is not iterable** is there anyway you can help me with this problem, there are two cases in this code where n can either be an integer or a tuple. Thanks for any help

Comment: Please include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: The way you are unpacking a tuple is wrong. Unpacking of a tuple can be done as follows (a,b) = n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `n` is a (two-element?) tuple - say, `(x,y)`. Then the line `for a,b in n:` is essentially equivalent to `for a,b in (x,y):`. At the first iteration of the loop, Python attempts to assign the first element of the tuple `x` to `a,b`, which is not possible.

You should replace the loop with an assignment `a,b=n`, or just use `n[0]` and `n[1]` instead of `a` and `b`.